# How to click on a board on trello with selenium+chrome+vba?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, trello

I want to automate some functions that I usually do on Trello, like create boards and lists.
I downloaded selenium IDE from chrome.  Now, I can enter on trello's website and login with my password.
But I don't know how to click on a board.
I have a `ul` list and I want to find the board by name and click.

```
      Public Sub seleniumtutorial()
      Dim bot As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver

      bot.Start "chrome", "https://trello.com/login"
      bot.get "/"

      bot.Type "name=user", "biaverly@id.uff.br"
      bot.Type "name=password", "mypassword"
      bot.clickAndWait "id=login"
```

OK UNTIL HERE

This is where I want do click

(https://scontent.fsdu13-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/61126356_2783547018382386_4366937053661757440_n.png?_nc_cat=110&_nc_ht=scontent.fsdu13-1.fna&oh=ac6b0ac6acc49e8ca3c2bcb54d105afa&oe=5D62AC25)

and I want do find by the name

(https://scontent.fsdu13-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/60763397_620930688408674_8385622658426863616_n.png?_nc_cat=109&_nc_ht=scontent.fsdu13-1.fna&oh=02f1f5766e149f32e1879a553c7a9d84&oe=5D9B1F82)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use className for that web element bec. it's made up from diff class. instead of class, you can use css selector to locate that element.

try this css selector **.boards-page-board-section .mod-no-sidebar**

you can use this css selector to locate by text **div[title='urtext']**